# Simply load JSON file and expose it on WebAPI's endpoint

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have created WebAPI. In it's `GET` method I want to load local JSON file and pass it as response. So that when someone accesses this endpoint he will get said JSON response. As I'm total newb with WebAPI and JSON I don't know where to start. Even though I searched a lot through web.

I need something like this (don't know actual functions and classes):

```
    // GET api/values
    public JSON Get()
    {
        var json = File.Load(pathtoJSON.json);
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a newb you can tackle this problem in three steps.

STEP I - Go through some basic tutorial on youtube [like these](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=webapi%20get%20simple).

STEP II - Create s basic controller (get method) and return a simple String like "Hello World!". Try it and see if you are getting the response.

STEP III - Now you got something working then try to read JSON file and send them as response.

EDIT: if still you got issues, here is some very basic code for you reference:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Http;

 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public UserData Get()
        {   
            UserData userData = null;
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\testjson.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(json);
            }

            return userData;
        }

        public class UserData {
            [JsonProperty("first_name")]
            public string FirstName;

            [JsonProperty("last_name")]
            public string LastName;

            [JsonProperty("age")]
            public String Age;
        }
    }
```

and testjson.json

```
{
"first_name":"FirstTest1",
"last_name":"LastTest1",
"age":"25"
}
```

and the response

[image]